# C# Changing stock quantity with ordered

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

After placing an order how would I then use the Quantity from the ShoppingCart to adjust the quantity from the Product in the database, lowering the stock available for purchase?

Here is my classes,
ShoppingCart Class with Create Order

```
 public int CreateOrder(Order order)
    {
        decimal orderTotal = 0;

        var cartItems = GetCartItems();

        // Iterate over the items in the cart, adding the order details for each
        foreach (var item in cartItems)
        {
            var orderDetail = new OrderDetail
            {
                ProductId = item.ProductId,
                OrderId = order.OrderId,
                UnitPrice = item.Product.Price,
                Quantity = item.Count
            };
            // Set the order total of the shopping cart
            orderTotal += (item.Count * item.Product.Price);

            storeDB.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);

        }
        // Set the order's total to the orderTotal count
        order.Total = orderTotal;

        // Save the order
        storeDB.SaveChanges();
        // Empty the shopping cart
        EmptyCart();
        // Return the OrderId as the confirmation number
        return order.OrderId;
    }
```

My Order Class

```
[Bind(Exclude = "OrderId")]
public partial class Order
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Remote("CheckUserName", "Account")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Your name is too long")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your last name is required.")]
    [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Last name is too long.")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required.")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postcode is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required.")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required.")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Email doesn't look like a valid email address.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Email")]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm your email address")]
    public string EmailConfirm { get; set; }


    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string PaymentTransactionId { get; set; }


    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool HasBeenShipped { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public CardDetails cardDetails { get; set; }
    //public List<CardDetails> cardDetails { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

My CheckOutController

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(FormCollection values)
        {
            var order = new Order();
            TryUpdateModel(order);

            //try
            //{
                //if (string.Equals(values["PromoCode"], PromoCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
                //{
                //    return View(order);
                //}
                //else
                //{
                    order.Username = User.Identity.Name;
                    order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;

                    //Order gets saved
                    storeDB.Orders.Add(order);
                    storeDB.SaveChanges();
                    //Order gets processed
                    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
                    cart.CreateOrder(order);

                    //NEW TEST IF SAVES
                    storeDB.SaveChanges();

                    //Model.Product.stock = item.Product.stock - item.count;



                    return RedirectToAction("Complete",
                        new { id = order.OrderId });
```

OrderDetails Class

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would like writing a procedure to deal with the transnational part.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: I think he means using a stored procedure. However, you question here is entirely unclear. You've got a line of code commented out that seems to at least be trying to do this. What issues are you having? What's not working? Also, we can't really help you modify something we have no visibility into. If there's an entity involved in tracking the stock. Post that entity class. Otherwise, we would need to see some sort of table structure.

Comment: That line of code was my attempt after looking into it myself, i just can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Yes, I think @SamGhatak was trying to say that you would want to handle adding the Order and reducing the Product stock as part of a transaction, and one way you could achieve this would be via a stored procedure. You could still do this purely with EF, but you need to update the stock on the EF Product entity (not the Model) before the call to SaveChanges().

Comment: The transaction stuff being talked about and upvoted here is entirely irrelevant. First of all, dbContext.SaveChanges is already transactional. But more importantly, an order does not immediately decrease stock. It is an **order**. Orders can have to be approved, or they can be placed in backorder when the requested quantity is not in stock. **Shipments** decrease the stock. So I hope this is homework and not a production application, because you've got a few things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can add these following codes in the ForEach loop of your ShoppingCart class

```
    // Get the product
    var product = storeDB.Products
        .Single(products => products.productID == item.ProductId);

    //Deduce available stock based on item in carts
    product.productQty = product.productQty - item.Count; 

    storeDB.saveChanges();
```

First get the product details and then deduce the product stock based on how many items are there in the cart.Finally do a saveChanges() to save in database.Hope this helps :)

Comment: @CodeCaster Please enlighten me I don't understand your statement.

Comment: Test the code with the given input. See also my comment under the question. You don't check the input, allowing users to order a negative amount or an amount greater than the current stock.

Comment: @CodeCaster I understand your point now and I agree with you on your comment under the question. This won't work on a production level and let's treat this as a homework . As for checking input, maybe adding data annotations for the property field 'Quantity' can check for negative amounts, while conditional statement can check for an amount greater than current stock.Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.